# css horizontal menu, vertical spacing

Tags: css

I have two horizontal rows of menu items. The bottom of the top row and the top of the bottom row have no spacing, they appear visually to merge
As an absolute beginner to CSS, I cant fathom out which line of coding to amend to get these two rows apart, a few px would do
Any advice would be appreciated

```html
<style>

.droplinetabs{
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    text-align: left; /* set to left, center, or right */
    font: bold 12px, verdana; 
}

.droplinetabs *{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.droplinetabs a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block; 
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    position: relative;
}
.droplinetabs ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
 perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
 perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
}

/* Top Level LI style */
.droplinetabs > li{
}

/* Top Level link style */
.droplinetabs > li > a{
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    background: #669900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Top Level link style on hover and when active */
.droplinetabs li:hover > a {
    background: #669900;
}

.droplinetabs li{
    display: inline;
}

/* drop line ULs style */
.droplinetabs ul{
    background: #669900;
    position: absolute;
    left: -5000px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0px 0;
    top: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #eee;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-70deg);
    transform: rotateX(-70deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s, -webkit-transform .5s, visibility 0s .3s, left 0s .3s;
    transition: opacity .3s, transform .5s, visibility 0s .3s, left 0s .3s;
}

/* Reveal sub menu on hover */
.droplinetabs li:hover > ul{
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, -webkit-transform .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s, transform .5s;
}

.droplinetabs ul li{
    display: inline;

}

/* Sub Levels link style on hover and when active */

.droplinetabs ul li:hover > a {
    background: #669900;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* LIs with a sub UL style */
.droplinetabs li > a {
    /* add padding to accomodate arrow inside LIs */
    padding-right: 30px;
}

/* LIs with NO sub UL style */
.droplinetabs li > a:only-child {
    /* undo padding for non submenu LIs */
    padding-right: 15px;
}


/* Arrow for LIs with sub ULs */
.droplinetabs li > a:after {
    /* add arrow inside LIs */
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: black;
    top: 45%;
    right: 8px;
}


/* LIs with NO sub UL pseudo class */
.droplinetabs li > a:only-child:after {
    /* undo arrow for non submenu LIs */
    display: none;
}

/* ####### responsive layout CSS ####### */

@media (max-width: 720px) {
/* Top Level link style */
    .droplinetabs > li > a{
       border-radius: 0;
       margin-top: 5px;
    }
    
}

</style>

.droplinetabs { font-family: Verdana ; font-size: 10px}

.droplinetabs { font-family: Verdana ; font-size: 12px; clip:     rect(   )}

.droplinetabs { 
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0;
 }
```

Comment: you need the html also

Comment: You got to at least give us the class or id of the rows you want to separate

Comment: How can I let you have the html code, pasting here is too many characters
Class or ID of the rows means nothing too me